# All Supported Ciphers in j2ssh Maverick 1.5.4

Tags: j2ssh

Lee:

We are using your j2ssh Maverick 1.5.4.  It works great.  However, we found that the default ciphers are aes128-ctr and 3des-ctr only.  But, according to API, there are many other ciphers supported in the library.  How should I code it so that all ciphers supported can be used?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other ciphers are Counter Block Mode (CBC) ciphers which are no longer advised. See https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/958563

You can add any of the cipher implementations in com.sshtools.ssh.components.jce back to the ComponentManager if you wish using the code below. Remember to add each cipher to both the client->server and server->client component factories.

```
ComponentManager.getInstance().supportedSsh2CiphersCS().add(
                    Ssh2Context.CIPHER_AES128_CBC, AES128Cbc.class);
ComponentManager.getInstance().supportedSsh2CiphersSC().add(
                    Ssh2Context.CIPHER_AES128_CBC, AES128Cbc.class);
```